# how to show preloader on loading contents by ajax on my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, preloader

i am currently working on a music site where i used ajax to load different pages and contents and all is working correctly but i need to show some kind of preload or loading or prease wait while ajax fetching data and stop that preload when its complete. this is the ajax code i am using to fetch my contents please any body help me how to achieve this.

```js
// handles the click event, sends the query
function getindex_page() {
    $.ajax({
        url:'templete.php',
        complete: function (response) {
            $('#main-container').html(response.responseText);
        },
        error: function () {
            $('#main-container').html('Bummer: there was an error!');
        },
    });
    return false;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu-items">
                        <li>
                            <a class="browse" href="/index.php" onclick="return getindex_page();"><i class="arcd-archive" ></i></br>Browse</a>                             
                        </li>
     </ul>
<div id="main-container"> ajax will loads contents here </div>
```

any help will be really appreciated.

Comment: Check this out https://code.google.com/p/jquery-loadmask/

Comment: Before the ajax call insert the loading.gif via HTML/CSS and then add a success call within the ajax that removes the loading.gif

Comment: can you please give me an example because i had already try this but image is shown there all the time or some times never shows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will want to change this to a spinner or whatever, but basically it's very easy:

```
// handles the click event, sends the query
function getindex_page() {
   $('#main-container').html('Loading... Please wait');
   // or change this to show a div that covers the page and has a spinner or whatever
   $.ajax({

      url:'templete.php',
    complete: function (response) {
        $('#main-container').html(response.responseText);
    },
    error: function () {
        $('#main-container').html('Bummer: there was an error!');
    },
});
return false; }
```

Main-container's html will be changed to Loading...... immediatly after the click event occurred and will be overridden on ajax complete. If you showed a spinner, simply hide it in your complete function.

Comment: thanks for your kind ans it seem its working because i am currently working on localhost it is extreamly fast even some times i can't see it now my questions are is there any way to slow it down so i see the effect and 2nd i have a spinner gif so how to use that instead of just using boring text 'Loading... Please wait' thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hi use the "beforeSend" function like this.
Then the load text will only be visible when the ajax call begins.

```js
function getindex_page() {
  var strLoadingText = 'Loading... Please wait';
  
  $.ajax({
    url:'templete.php',
    beforeSend: function () {
      $('#main-container').html(strLoadingText);
    },
    complete: function (response) {
        $('#main-container').html(response.responseText);
    },
    error: function () {
        $('#main-container').html('Bummer: there was an error!');
    },
});
  
  return false; 
}
```